# Is it possible that fireEvent.click from @testing-library/react re-renders the component with its initial state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a React Component (Comp) with an input element and a button element. I wrote a test to verify that empty input is parsed correctly.

Problem:

1) input's value is assigned to be "" (input has `onChange={ e => this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value }) }`)

2) `fireEvent.click(container.querySelector('#calculateButton'))` is called

^note: button has `onClick={e => this.onCalculateButtonClick(e)}`, which obtains inputValue from state

3) `userInput.split(',')` is invoked inside of`onCalculateButtonClick`

4) An exception is thrown: **TypeError: userInput.split is not a function** because userInput is 0 (a number).

The only way I can explain this is if somehow fireEvent.click reset Component's state to it's default (inputValue: 0)

Here's the code:

```
class Comp extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            inputValue: 0,
            calculationResult: '',
        };
    }
    onCalculateButtonClick = function(event) {
        const userInput = this.state.inputValue; // this is 0 after fireEvent.click is called
        const tokenizedInput = userInput.split(',').map(element => { // exception thrown here
    ...
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Comp">
    ...
                        <input
                            id="userInput"
                            type="text"
                            onChange={ e => this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value }) }
                        />
    ...
                    <button
                        id="calculateButton"
                        onClick={e => this.onCalculateButtonClick(e)}
                    >
                        Calculate
                    </button>
    }
}
```

And the test (jest):

```
test('empty input returns 0', () => {
    const { container } = render(<Calculator />);
    const inputElement = container.querySelector('#userInput');
    fireEvent.change(inputElement, { target: { value: '' } }); // after this line, inputElement is ''
    fireEvent.click(container.querySelector('#calculateButton')); // throws exception here from inputElement being 0??
    const outputElement = container.querySelector('#calculationResult');
    expect(outputElement.innerHTML).toBe('0');
});
```

I have no idea why fireEvent.change would cause my state's inputValue property to be 0 - would love to understand what's going on here. Tried to be as clear as possible, let me know if anything is still unclear. Thanks!